# Formatter registry SPI- Overide springs default date format with a custom date format

Tags: spring, registry, date-format, formatter

I am trying to use Formatter registry SPI for overriding the default date format returned by Spring as part of a response. However, the custom implementation is not taking effect. I referred to this GitHub repo and links and they suggest the usage of formatter registry so and so, but can't find somewhere this is used to override the default date format centrally. Is this possible? Can someone point to any useful resources which explain the usage in this context?

Formatter registry SPI- I might want to enforce that all Date fields are formatted a certain way(preferred date format) and apply this rule throughout the application. Does anyone share the working GitHub sample for executing the same behavior to our application?
Currently, I am facing an issue while implementing the Formatter registry SPI

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomDateFormatterRegistrar implements FormatterRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService =
                new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();

        // Set your custom date format pattern
        registrar.setDateFormatter(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        registrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);
        // Register the custom date formatter
        registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class DateConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomDateFormatterRegistrar customDateFormatterRegistrar() {
        return new CustomDateFormatterRegistrar();
    }

}
```